# Output children of a structure section in reverse order

Tags: structure, sections, ordering

How do you output the all the children of a structure in a reverse order (assuming the children are limited to max depth).

Using the [order parameter](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/craft.entries#order), Craft requires that you use a second parameter like `"desc"` after a primary order parameter (eg, `"title"`). This would look like:

```
craft.entries.section('volumes').order('title desc')
```

But what would be the primary parameter that would respect the natural structure order?

Or is there any other way?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The primary parameter you're looking for is `lft`:

```
craft.entries.section('volumes').order('lft desc')
```

Comment: Thanks carlcs. Very useful. Handy that the Craft documentation fails to mention that parameter!

Answer (score 8):

You could <s>try using</s> use the `reverse` twig filter.

```
{% for entry in craft.entries.section('volumes')|reverse %}
...
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Wouldn't this just reverse the default order, which is `'postDate desc'`?

Comment: IGNORE my comment. If it's a structure, the default order is in fact the sort order of the entries in the CP. Just tried the `reverse` filter and it works as you said.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. This should also be the answer but because carlcs's answer addresses the first method of solving the problem, I thought it more suitable to tick that one.

Comment: No worries. I like his answer also. I learned something new! ;)